# How does Astronaut.io hides the "watch later" , the uploader's profile picture and "share" logo on their youtube embedded player?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

On some of the youtube videos (not all of them), the astronaut.io script manages to remove the uploader's profile picture, the watch later logo and the share logo. I was wondering if someone could tell me how they managed to remove that much information out of their embedded player.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="p2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player" width="1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fastronaut.io&widgetid=2" height="0" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;"></iframe>
```

look at the `src` of the `iframe` that the video is in. You'll see it has some parameters after a `?`, separated by `&`s. This bit after the `?` is called a `query string` and it's how you pass parameters via a `URL`. The one's here are:

```
controls = 0
showinfo = 0
modestbranding = 1
enablejsapi = 1
origin = http://astronaut.io
widgetid = 2
```

you'll notice that `origin` has some weird characters in it, that's because if you sent `:` and `/` directly it would mess things up, so they have to represented a different way.

It looks like `showinfo = 0` and `controls = 0` are probably what's causing the behaviour you're observing. If not, it's definitely some combination of the ones above.

Comment: Thing is that showinfo is now deprecated. When I put all of these parameters I still have these icons. Is it possible that website who were made before the deprecation of certain parameters are able to still use them?